# SandBoxed Visual Webpart for SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-part

I have created a new visual web part in SharePoint 2013 as a sandboxed solution. I can see the web part in the Webpart gallery. But when I Click F5 in my VS.net, the web part is working fine. As soon as I stop debugging, the web part is not working. I can see the following error.

> The request could not be completed because the specified solution was not found.. - Validating solution failed

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

By default, Visual Studio retracts the Sandbox Solution when you stop debugging. You can control this functionality using the checkbox at the bottom of the SharePoint settings for your project.

[image]